# Keep startIcon at top left position when using multi-line textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I've got the following layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/vehicle_type"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_default"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_notes_24">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

which looks like this:

[image: current view]

My goal is that the startIcon should remain at the top position:

[image: goal view]

Is that possible?
I've looked into the options, which can be used for the `TextInputLayout`, however there doesn't seem any "gravity" option for the `startIcon`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The startIcon is defined by a `CheckableImageButton` inflated with the  [`design_text_input_start_icon`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/layout/design_text_input_start_icon.xml) layout

There isn't a public API to get it , but as workaround you can use:

```
    val textField = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.textfield)
    val startIcon: CheckableImageButton =
        textField.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.text_input_start_icon)

    val layoutParams = startIcon.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    layoutParams.apply {
        gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will be possible. Other than sub-classing the view and doing something there (haven't looked or tried), I think the best you can do is to overlay the view with another view that holds the drawable and is positioned to the top/left.

Comment: Interesting. So _TextInputLayout_ already extends _LinearLayout_, so no additional structure is needed to shift the drawable. It is unfortunate, however, that these seemingly simple manipulations require a knowledge of the internal structure of the view.